# How to display posts by current user in a drop down

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7

I am trying to write a shortcode that works in conjunction with Contact Form 7 to display the current user that is logged in posts.

I have been able to get it to work with regular posts using this code here:

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode('postdropdown', 'createbox', true);
    function createbox(){
    global $post;
    $args = array('numberposts' => 0);
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    $output = "<select name='cursus' id='cursus' onchange='document.getElementById(\"cursus\").value=this.value;'><option></option>";
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
        $title = get_the_title();
        $output .= "<option value='$title'> $title </option>";

        endforeach;
    $output .= "</select>";
    return $output;
}
```

However i am not sure how to go about adapting it for to display only the posts that the currently logged in user posted.

Any help and direction on this would be welcome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'author' => get_current_user_id()` as an argument for `get_posts()`. This will restrict the found posts to these of the user which is currently logged in.

The best reference for the available parameters is still `WP_Query::parse_query()` in `wp-includes/query.php`. It is not exactly an atomic function, but you can find parameters not documented elsewhere – like this one.

Tow notes abut your code:

1. Your `onchange` handler looks a little bit strange. It doesn’t do anything, does it?
2. Do not use `get_the_title()` for attribute values. The post title can contain markup.
   Use `the_title_attribute( array ( 'echo' => FALSE ) );` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I was having a major brain fart. This worked perfectly. :)

Comment: @Nicole I made a small update.

Comment: I actually removed the onchange as it was used for something else. However I did change the title. Thanks for the update. :)